# Select specific value of dropdown list depending on numeric value from a cell

Tags: vba

I have the following:

- A form control on sheet 3 conditioned to cell B1.
- A drop-down list of data validation on sheet 1 that has 3 options (A, B, C)
- A dropdown list of data validation on sheet 2 that has 2 options (C, D)

I need a macro that does the following:

- If cell B1 = 1 then choose the value A from the list on sheet 1 and the value C from sheet 2.
- If cell B1 = 2 then choose the value B from the list on sheet 1 and the value C on sheet 2
- If cell B1 = 3 then choose the C value from the list on sheet 1 and the D value from sheet 2.

The general idea that I have reviewed is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)

  If [B1] = 1 Then
     Call Macro_1
  End If
  If [B1] = 2 Then
     Call Macro_2
  End If
  If [B1] = 3 Then
     Call Macro_3
  End If

End Sub
```

But I do not know how to make a macro that I choose the specific values of each list.

Comment: Also review Select Case statements or If ElseIF End If, and your CALL keywords are likely obselete.

Comment: An image might paint a thousand words here (though i recognise this is not an option for everyone).